# Does shapely within function identify inner holes?

Tags: python, shapely

I have a series of shapefiles that include both polygons and multipolygons. I am using ogr to extract them in wkb, and them I am using shapely to check if a point fall inside a polygon (or a multipolygon). However, examining some of the polygons in wkb I realized that many of them have inner rings (i.e. I have a set of coordinates describing the first, outer polygon, and a set of coordinates describing the inner polygon/s). Does the shapely `within` function take care of this, I mean, does it return `True` only if a point falls in the area delimited by outer and inner polygons? And are the inner polygons always supposed to be holes?

I am sorry, perhaps these are really dumb questions, but I am completely new to this kind of analyses and, despite my efforts, I could not find some clear information about these doubts. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `polygon.exterior` and `polygon.interiors` is helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'Yes' is the short answer to your question.  Interior rings in a single polygon are always holes.  The exterior ring comes first followed by a list of interior rings (holes).  A polygon must also be non-self-intersecting. Multipolygons are merely a list of polygons bundled together, but the structure of each consituent polygon in the list follows the same structure as for a single 'stand-alone' polygon.  So, The interior rings of the constituent polygons of a multipolygon are also holes.  Shapely honours this, so if your point falls in the hole, the tests `.within` and `.contains` will both return `False`.

You can test this very easily as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point

# construct a valid polygon (i.e. not self-intersecting) with a hole
ext = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]
int = [(1, 1), (1, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 1)]
myPoly = Polygon(ext,[int])

# construct a point that is within the bounds of the exterior ring but inside the hole
myPoint = Point(1.25, 1.25)
print(myPoint.within(myPoly))  # returns 'False'

# construct a point that is inside the polygon (avoiding the hole)
myOtherPoint = Point(0.5, 0.5)
print(myOtherPoint.within(myPoly))  # returns 'True'
```

Comment: Thank you very much MappaGnosis, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, holes are accounted for. Within means within the point set, not within the exterior ring.

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> circle = Point(0.0, 0.0).buffer(2.0)
>>> circle
<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1003eb0d0>
>>> circle.area
12.546193962183755
>>> donut = circle.difference(Point(0.0, 0.0).buffer(1.0))
>>> donut
<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1003eb110>
>>> donut.area
9.409645471637816
>>> Point(0.0, 0.0).within(donut)
False
```