# create a pie shaped object in shapely and export to gis polygon object

Tags: python, shapely

I would like to create a pie chart-shaped polygon with concentric layers like so:
[image: pie example]

I can create this simple object with:

```
from math import sin, cos, radians 
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString

#variables for buffers
coordinates = (0,0)
point = Point(coordinates)
buffers=[]
outerRadius=100
numberOfCircles=5
radiusStep= outerRadius/numberOfCircles
innerRadius=radiusStep
pi=3.1415


#create the buffers
while innerRadius<=outerRadius:
    buffers.append(point.buffer(innerRadius,200))
    innerRadius+=radiusStep


#variables for linestrings 
centerX = coordinates[0]
centerY = coordinates[1]
coordX=[]
coordY=[]
lines=[]

#create linestrings for circles
for i in xrange(1,361,45):
    xCoord = centerX + outerRadius * cos(radians(i))
    coordX.append(xCoord)
    yCoord = centerY + outerRadius * sin(radians(i))
    coordY.append(yCoord)
    line = LineString([(centerX,centerY),(xCoord,yCoord)])
    lines.append(line)
```

**My question is this:**

How can I take multiple shapely objects of different geometries and create a geofile (geojson, shapefile, etc...) so that each section of the "pie" is treated as a separate polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) and the `mapping` function of shapely

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import fiona
# schema of the shapefile (or GeoJSON file, or...) for the lines
schema = {'geometry': 'LineString','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('lines.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
   for i in lines:
       e.write({'geometry':mapping(i), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

Result:

[image]

You can do the same thing with the buffers but you'll never get a ring polygon as result with your solution (only a superposition of polygons)

You need to use the solution given by [MappaGnosis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/5222/mappagnosis) in [Does shapely within function identify inner holes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72306/does-shapely-within-function-identify-inner-holes)

```
one = list(buffers[1].exterior.coords)
interior = LinearRing(one)
exterior = LinearRing(list(buffers[2].exterior.coords)
ring = Polygon(exterior,[interior])
#  new schema
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
# write the shapefile
with fiona.open('ring.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
    e.write({'geometry':mapping(ring), 'properties':{'test':1}})
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Interesting feature of the library, thanks for your help.