# How to Automate Symmetric Difference using OGR in Python

Tags: python, ogr, symmetric-difference

I need to try and automate the process of creating mask layers by using the symmetric difference of two different polygon layer files (they are currently in .TAB format, however these can be converted to .shp if need be) using OGR in Python.

The following is the code:

```
outputFileName = new+"mask.TAB"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("MapInfo File")
f1 = driver.Open(new+boundname,0)
layer1 = f1.GetLayer(0)
feature1 = layer1.GetNextFeature()

if f1 is None:
  print "Could not open file ", f1
  sys.exit(1)

f2 = driver.Open(new+regionname,0)
layer2 = f2.GetLayer(0)

if f2 is None:
print "Could not open file ", f2

### Create output file ###
if os.path.exists(outputFileName):
  os.remove(outputFileName)
try:
  output = driver.CreateDataSource(outputFileName)
except:
  print 'Could not create output datasource ', outputFileName
  sys.exit(1)

newLayer = output.CreateLayer('SymmetricDifference',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon,srs=layer1.GetSpatialRef())

if newLayer is None:
  print "Could not create output layer"
  sys.exit(1)

newLayerDef = newLayer.GetLayerDefn()

featureID = 0

while feature1:

  layer2.ResetReading()
  geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
  feature2 = layer2.GetNextFeature()

  while feature2:

    geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()

    if geom1.Overlaps(geom2) == 1:
        newgeom = geom1.SymDifference(geom1,geom2)
        newFeature = ogr.Feature(newLayerDef)
        newFeature.SetGeometry(newgeom)
        newFeature.SetFID(featureID)
        newLayer.CreateFeature(newFeature)
        featureID += 1
        newFeature.Destroy()

    else:
        newFeature1 = ogr.Feature(newLayerDef)
        newFeature1.SetGeometry(geom1)
        newFeature1.SetFID(featureID)
        newLayer.CreateFeature(newFeature1)

        featureID += 1
        newFeature2 = ogr.Feature(newLayerDef)
        newFeature2.SetGeometry(geom2)
        newFeature2.SetFID(featureID)
        newLayer.CreateFeature(newFeature2)
        featureID += 1

        newFeature1.Destroy()
        newFeature2.Destroy()

    feature2.Destroy()
    feature2 = layer2.GetNextFeature()

feature1.Destroy()
feature1 = layer1.GetNextFeature()

f1.Destroy()
f2.Destroy()
```

From this, I get the following output:

[image]

However, what I actually want this script to do is create a hole in the larger polygon as shown below

[image]

Any ideas where I am going wrong in the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple, you don't need `if f1 is None`and others (assuming that you know the shapefiles to handle) in a simple personal script.

Here is a simple solution with your data (with one polygon in each shapefile)

[image]

```
from osgeo import ogr
poly1 = ogr.Open('poly1.shp')
poly2 = ogr.Open('poly2.shp')
layer1 = poly1.GetLayer()
layer1.GetFeatureCount()
1
# first feature
feature1 = layer1.GetFeature(0)
# geometry
geom1 = feature.GetGeometryRef()
layer2 = poly2.GetLayer()
layer2.GetFeatureCount()
 1
# first feature
feature2 = layer2.GetFeature(0)
# geometry
geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
# symmetric difference
simdiff = geom1.SymmetricDifference(geom2)
# create a new shapefile
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
data_source = driver.CreateDataSource("result.shp")
layer = data_source.CreateLayer("result",None, ogr.wkbPolygon)
feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
feature.SetGeometry(simdiff)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
feature.Destroy()
data_source.Destroy()
```

[image]

It is easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (simplification of ogr) and [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, shape, mapping
poly1 = fiona.open("poly1.shp")
poly2 = fiona.open("poly2.shp")
# transformation of geometry to shapely geometry (one element )
geom1 = [shape(feat['geometry']) for feat in poly1)][0]
geom2 = [shape(feat['geometry']) for feat in poly2][0]
# creation of the resulting shapefile
with fiona.open("result2.shp", 'w',driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=poly1.schema) as output:
   prop = {'id': 1}
   output.write({'geometry': mapping(geom1.symmetric_difference(geom2)), 'properties':prop})
```

Another solution is to directly create a [Polygon with holes (Shapely)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/72311/2581) (or [Polygon with holes (ogr)](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#create-a-polygon-with-holes)) with the two polygons

```
pol1 = list(geom1.exterior.coords)
pol2 = list(geom2.exterior.coords)
pol_hole = Polygon(pol1,[pol2])
with fiona.open("result3.shp", 'w',driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=poly1.schema) as output:
   prop = {'id': 1}
   output.write({'geometry': mapping(pol_hole), 'properties':prop})
```

And for your problem

```
with fiona.open('symdiff.shp','w',...) as output1:
   with fiona.open('normal.shp', 'w',...) as output2:
     for i in geoms1:
         for j in geoms2:
             if i.overlaps(j):
                # write the symdifference shapefile
             else:
                #write the normal shapefile
```

Comment: Thanks very much Gene! This worked perfectly, I got my desired result with this much simpler method. I am sure this will help many others in the future who may have similar questions regarding symmetric difference.