# "Invert" a multipolygon/polygon with a hole and take the interior polygon

Tags: python, polygon

I'm a Python developer and am currently struggling with an issue.
I have a multipolygon with a "hole" in the center and I need to extract the middle polygon.
For example, this is the polygon I have:

[image]

I need the blue highlighted area:

[image]

I have tried getting either the convex hull or the envelope of the polygon and then extracting the difference, but sometimes the polygon is not as even and I'm getting "noise" around the edges.

I'm not as experienced in GIS. Is there a more straight-forward way I'm missing?

Comment: Have a look at 'interior ring', things like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824157/how-to-extract-interior-polygon-coordinates-using-shapely or https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.get_interior_ring.html to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72306/does-shapely-within-function-identify-inner-holes

Comment: Which geometry library are you using?

Comment: Is this a vector or raster(image) format? What do you mean by "noise"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't specify what python geospatial library you are using, but here is a geopandas solution:

Given input.shp:

[image]

Extract the interior rings and convert them to multipolygons:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
from typing import Union


def get_holes(geometry: Union[Polygon, MultiPolygon]) -> MultiPolygon:  # if Python 3.10+ just use get_holes(geometry: Polygon|MultiPolygon) -> MultiPolygon
    """ Given a Polygon/MultiPolygon geometry object,
        return a MultiPolygon of the interior rings
        or None if the geometry has no interior rings """
    if type(geometry) is Polygon:
        geometry = MultiPolygon([geometry])
    holes = []
    for geom in geometry.geoms:
        holes += [Polygon(ring) for ring in geom.interiors]
    if bool(holes):
        return MultiPolygon(holes)



gdf = gpd.read_file("input.shp")
gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(get_holes)


print(gdf)

gdf.to_file("output.shp")
```

Output.shp

```
id                                           geometry
1  MULTIPOLYGON (((129.95504 -23.96904, 129.84755...
2  MULTIPOLYGON (((130.10552 -31.34290, 132.08335...
3                                               None
```

[image]